# Using C# to operate AD LDS how to verify user and password without putting this user to administrator group

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, adlds

I'm trying to use C# to operate AD LDS.

I can already connect to AD by my administrator account. Like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverip/CN=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=com", username, password,AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
```

The 'username' and 'password' are administrator and it's password.

Then I create a user on my server. And I set its `UserPrincipalName as 'william'` and its password. I also set its `msDS-UserAccountDisabled = false`

I try to log this user with C#

```
Directory entry = new Directory("LDAP:\\serverid\CN=xxx,DC=YYY,DC=com",username,pwd,AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
entry.RefreshCache();
```

When I didn't put 'william' into 'Administrator' group, the code `entry.RefreshCache();` always throw an Exception; but when I put 'william' into 'Adminitrator', this code suddenly works.

I suppose it is a problem about permission, but I can't figure out it.

Can anyone tell me why this can works. And how can I change this method. You know I don't want make user be administrator.

Comment: What exact error do you receive on RefreshCache execution?

Comment: Now I have tried to connect to openldap but I always get an error:An invalid DN syntax has been specified.

Comment: Please share your code of user creation. Check that the user really exists via ADSIEdit. If you create user with DirectoryEntry verify that UseCache property is set to false

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  I have alreay solved this problem by using the LdapConnection class.  I find that this class can connect to both OpenLdap and AD LDS